# Remove duplicate approximate word matching using fuzzy python

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy

I would like to ask on how to remove duplicate approximate word matching using fuzzy in python or **ANY METHOD** that is feasible. I have an excel that contains approximate similar name, at this point, I would like to remove the name that contains high similarity and remain only one name.

For instance, here is the input (excel file), there is 6 rows and 5 columns in total:

```
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| abby_john         | abc | abc | abc | abc | abc |
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| abby_johnny       | def | def | def | def | def |  
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| a_j               | ghi | ghi | ghi | ghi | ghi |  
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| abby_(john)       | abc | abc | abc | abc | abc |  
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| john_abby_doe     | def | def | def | def | def | 
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| aby_/_John_Doedy  | ghi | ghi | ghi | ghi | ghi |  
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Although all the above of name looks different, they actually is the same, how should python know they all are the same and remove duplicated name and remains **ANY ONE** of name and remains it's entire row? By the way, the input file is in Excel file format (.xlsx).

Desired output:

```
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| abby_john         | abc | abc | abc | abc | abc |
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Since the underscore is not very important, it can be replaced with 'spacing', thus another output as following is acceptable:
Another desired output:

```
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|  
| abby_john         | abc | abc | abc | abc | abc |
|-------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Appreciate a lot if anyone can help me out, thanks!

Comment: `a_j` is quite dissimilar to the rest, no?

Comment: what if a_j is forced to be similar to the rest, does it still possible to be solved?

Comment: I'll post an answer. But it doesn't handle the `a_j` as similar.

Comment: Great!! thanks a lot, bro! by the way, I've edited the input data, could you mind to use the revised input data? thanks in advance

Comment: I used the revised input data with a couple of added entries, too. The other answer is good, and less code!

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro! I will try your code later, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function to correct and replace names and then I remove the duplicate matches, maintaining only the first match

```
import difflib
import re

def similarity_replace(series):

    reverse_map = {}
    diz_map = {}
    for i,s in series.iteritems():
        diz_map[s] = re.sub(r'[^a-z]', '', s.lower())
        reverse_map[re.sub(r'[^a-z]', '', s.lower())] = s

    best_match = {}
    uni = list(set(diz_map.values()))
    for w in uni:
        best_match[w] = sorted(difflib.get_close_matches(w, uni, n=3, cutoff=0.5), key=len)[0]

    return series.map(diz_map).map(best_match).map(reverse_map)

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['abby_john','abby_johnny','a_j','abby_(john)','john_abby_doe','aby_/_John_Doedy'],
                       'col1':['abc','add','sda','sas','sad','ass'],
                       'col2':['abc','add','sda','sas','sad','ass'],
                       'col3':['abc','add','sda','sas','sad','ass']})

df['name'] = similarity_replace(df.name)
df
```

[image]

```
df.drop_duplicates(['name'])
```

[image]

a_j seems not possible to remove

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro! I will definitely try it and would let you know if it works, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

This is a class of problem called [semantic similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity).

Get the data:

```
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO("""abby_john         abc   abc   abc   abc 
abby_johnny       def   def   def   def 
a_j               ghi   ghi   ghi   ghi 
abby_(john)       abc   abc   abc   abc 
abby_john_doe     def   def   def   def 
aby_John_Doedy    ghi   ghi   ghi   ghi
abby john         ghi   ghi   ghi   ghi
john_abby_doe     def   def   def   def
aby_/_John_Doedy  ghi   ghi   ghi   ghi
doe jane          abc   abc   abc   abc
doe_jane          def   def   def   def""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(s,header=None,sep='\s+')
lst_original = df[0].tolist() # the first column
```

[Vectorize](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) (turn into numerical representation):

```
import numpy as np 
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

m = Word2Vec(lst_original,size=50,min_count=1,cbow_mean=1)  
def vectorizer(sent,m): 
    vec = [] 
    numw = 0 
    for w in sent: 
        try: 
            if numw == 0: 
                vec = m[w] 
            else: 
                vec = np.add(vec, m[w]) 
            numw += 1 
        except Exception as e: 
            print(e) 
    return np.asarray(vec) / numw 

l = []
for i in lst_original:
    l.append(vectorizer(i,m))

X = np.array(l)
```

[KMeans clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

clf = KMeans(n_clusters=2,init='k-means++',n_init=100,random_state=0)
labels = clf.fit_predict(X)
```

Then we get just the values where the cluster alternates:

```
previous_cluster = 0
for index, sentence in enumerate(lst_original):
    if index > 0:
        previous_cluster = labels[index - 1]
    cluster = labels[index]
    if previous_cluster != cluster:
        print(str(labels[index]) + ":" + str(sentence))
```

Result, and as you can see `a_j` is treated differently to the rest of the `abby_john` group:

```
1:a_j
0:abby_(john)
1:doe jane
```

Comment: ok, thanks bro! I will try your code later, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, mechanical_meat, I had tried on your code, it returned error ```NameError: name 'lst_original' is not defined```, may i know why is this error occurrence?

Comment: Ok, tell me how it works out when you get a chance! :)

Comment: Ya, it worked perfectly! May I know what is the meaning of ```1:a_j
0:abby_(john)
1:doe jane```? what is '1:' and '0:' represents?

Comment: Great to hear! The 0 and 1 are the clusters of similarity. Then we take only the first of each alternating cluster for the result. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is that means 1 represents dissimilar while 0 represents similar?

Comment: Not exactly. It means that the similar ones are grouped into either 0 or 1. So in the data when there is a dissimilar element the number changes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.

Comment: is that means 'a_j' and 'doe jane' is in one group since they both show '1' while 'abby_(john)' is in another group since it shows '0'?

Comment: No, the groups alternate. So each of those are in separate groups.

Comment: Hi, @mechanical_meat, can I ask a favor from you?

Comment: @EdisonToh: what's the favor?

Comment: I am actually needs your help on my another post regarding fuzzy matching problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874002/copy-approximate-string-matching-from-excel-to-another-excel-file-using-python, however, the problem has been solved, thanks anyway!!

Comment: Oh, by the same answer too! Nice.

Comment: Ya, thanks for your response for preparing to help out!

Comment: m[w] dont work in gensim 4 now use m.wv[w]